# Table view not get displayed in android

Tags: android

Im a newbie to android and with the help of some experts i write some code for displaying texts tableview in android.

Here is compiling without any errors but the app is not launching and the message "Unfortunately stopped working" error is showing.

```
HellotableActivity.java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloTableLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/Open..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/sujiO"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/Save..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/CtrlS"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloTableLayoutActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">HelloTableLayout</string>
    <string name="Open...">HelloTableLayout</string>
    <string name="sujiO">HelloTableLayout</string>
    <string name="Save...">HelloTableLayout</string>
    <string name="CtrlS">HelloTableLayout</string>
</resources>
```

Can anyone please help me with where im going wrong in this case.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableRow` and `TableView` don't work in `LinearLayout`, use `TableLayout` instead.

See the [Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html) example, which demonstrates very well how to use a `TableLayout`.

By the way, you cannot use dots in string names. How would you refer them in Java? I think standard is lowercase separated with underscores. ([Dev Guide Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String))